# How can I extract all elements inside android list view using appium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium

Below is my code my list view showing 7 items but list view contains 25 items how to click all the items one by one. Anyone can help me to solve my problem.

```
Boolean foundResult = false;
while (!foundResult) {
    List<WebElement> elements = DriverSetup.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@resource-id='app.mangalam.billboy:id/lv_master_receipts']/android.widget.LinearLayout"));
    int size=0;
    size=size + elements.size();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("android.widget.LinearLayout")).click();
        String lastElement = elements.get(12).findElement(By.className("android.widget.LinearLayout")).getText();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DriverSetup.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Navigate up']")).click();

        String s =elements.get(i).getText();
        if (s.equals(lastElement)) {
               found=true;
            System.out.println(size);
            System.out.println(found);
            break;

        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        DriverSetup.verticalScroll();
    }
}
```